# Bearded dragon has tilted head and doesn't move it, what can be done?

Tags: bearded-dragon

I gave my bearded dragon a bath, but didn't realize my there was chlorine in my water source. He's tilting his head and won't move it, so is there anything I can do or is he dying? I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how (or why) you gave your bearded dragon a bath, but short-term exposure to the the amount of chlorine/chloramine in a municipal water source is not going to cause the effect you describe. There is no home cure-all for what you are seeing. If you suspect any type of undue lethargy or lack of movement, you need to visit a vet as soon as possible.

Comment: It may have been water temp.  They are cold blooded.  If the water was too cold you might get those symptoms.

Comment: long short, if you don't take it to a vet, your beardie is going to die.Sorry